# Проблема с множественным наследованием в python

Tags: python, pyqt, объекты, наследование, множественное-наследование

Пытаюсь создать свой класс, унаследованный от двух классов (python 3.11):

```
from PyQt6.QtCore import QSemaphore, QObject    

class LimitPerMinuteSemaphore(QObject, QSemaphore):
    def __init__(self, limit_per_minute: int):
        super(QObject, self).__init__()
        super(QSemaphore, self).__init__(limit_per_minute)

semaphore = LimitPerMinuteSemaphore(200)
```

При создании переменной класса возникает ошибка (в строчке `super(QSemaphore, self).__init__(limit_per_minute)`):

> TypeError: QObject(parent: typing.Optional[QObject] = None): argument
> 1 has unexpected type 'int'

Почему возникает ошибка и как её исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QObject` [не поддерживает](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/moc.html#:%7E:text=Virtual%20inheritance%20with%20QObject%20is%20not%20supported.) виртуальное наследование.

> Virtual inheritance with QObject is not supported.

Как исправить: пересмотрите архитектуру вашего проекта.